# Has a virus ruined my motherboard and/or CPU?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, display, motherboard, windows-installation

This is my first time posting and it's honestly my last resort before I just let this machine turn into a paper weight and save up for a fresh start. I'm hoping someone makes me feel like an idiot with some simple solution, but here goes:

I recently downloaded a bad program that installed a folder in program files called "tew". Within this folder was a few .exe files that were obviously sketchy. (bleats.exe, My Internet.exe, etc.) and had strange company names when I went into 'Add/Remove Progams'. After removing them, they kept showing back up, along with ano error message being spammed every 3 seconds from another program called "network" saying that it couldn't connect to the web (probably to keep downloading bad software). The cpu started heating up from all the spam and whatever else was going on outside of my observations, so I shut down and decided to scrap the info on the drive by reinstalling win7 ultimate.
HOWEVER, after loading it, I can start the install process, but for some reason I lose connection to my monitor, and the machine just sits there humming, never completing the install or anything. I am totally stuck. I've also tried running the repair program on the boot dvd but it just stays in a state of "searching for problems" forever (30 minutes is the longest I waited for results). I have an Ubuntu boot disk, and may try to use it if I don't get any answers soon, to try and wipe the old info from the drive. Hopefully after all of the old info is gone I can install win7 as if it were a brand new hard drive. 
Should I scrap it? Should I reinstall my motherboard drivers? Is this something beyond the abilities of a novice pc builder or could I find step-by-step instructions for fixing my problems? This place is my last hope.
Please help me, PC guru's ^_^

Comment: At this point the fastest diagnostic would probably to try installing Ubuntu to see if it suffers the same problems.  It's unlikely that a virus would physically damage hardware but if the computer was having temperature control problems, it could certainly have made it worse and indeed damaged it.

Comment: You can use disk part While booting Win 7 go to command prompt to wipe your HDD and reinstall the OS. After successful full format you will be free from virus. if you have machines on lan that will also be also affected.

Answer (score 0):

I would be incredibly surprised if any firmware or the bios has been damaged.

Boot into Ubuntu and copy **all** your documents, movies, music etc. to a portable hard drive. (Windows malware can't do anything on Linux so it's totally safe.)

Disconnect the USB HDD then write a new partition table with Gparted and you'll be all good.**(That will delete all partitions and all data on your built in HDD.)**

Reinstall Windows 7 (Or 10 from the official Microsoft ISO that's available to anyone.)

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

(Burn the ISO from an Ubuntu install not your current messed up Windows install, use Xburn or K3B. The default Ubuntu disk burner (Brasero) is unreliable)

**Edit: To be sure there's no Windows autorun malware on your USB storage write a new partition table to that too before you back up your stuff.**

**Remember writing partition tables and deleting or formating partitions will delete *all* data.**

Comment: Apparently windows 10 iso is no longer free but I can try making a boot disk for it. The download is available through the "tool" that you can access at the address you gave but I think I'll need a product key. I'm installing Ubuntu now, but I noticed that I can't format any of the new partitions into NTFS, and I had trouble making win7 format partitions in the past. If there is a way to do it in command prompt during win7 install, I would try that but I'm afraid that I don't know how to mess with anything in there. Too technical unless I have some instructions

Comment: Forgive my comment. I found Gparted in Ubuntu software and it formatted a partition for me splendidly. Let's hope I don't have any more display errors during win7 install and then I'll be free of all trouble.

Comment: At this point I can only assume that I need to update bios or something. I can't make it to the installation process without the system randomly going to black "no signal" screen